# What are the differences between JWT RS256, RS384, and RS512 algorithms?

Tags: security, jwt, private-key, public-key

I'm using JWT RS256 algorithm in my current project, but I'm wondering what are the differences between algorithms RS256, RS384, and RS512. Can someone explain to me what are the key differences in these algorithms?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is the set of algorithms defined for use with JWS in [RFC 7518 -JSON Web Algorithms (JWA)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.1)

[image: algorithms]

The difference between `RS256`, `RS384`, and `RS512` is the hashing algorithm `SHA256`, `SHA384` and `SHA512`